# Shorten this into a function

Tags: c#, function, for-loop, paramarray

This program organises WMI data into a set of classes - one class for each hardware element in a computer - and each class is initialised multiple times if more than one of a particular hardware element exists.

Is there a nice neat way of turning this section of code into a few function calls? I was thinking of something along the lines of `CreateComponent(ref object dataClass, params string[] WMIClasses);` to initialise a computer component rather than using temporary stores for WMI data and making a for loop to add each instance.

```
        // These temporary stores fetch WMI data as ManagementObjects
        // Most cases will only need one WMI class.
        ManagementObject[] WMIDataTemp1;
        ManagementObject[] WMIDataTemp2;

        // Fetch data as ManagementObjects
        WMIDataTemp1 = DataRetriever.GetWMIData("Win32_Processor");
        // Loop though each ManagementObject and add a new device for each instance
        foreach (ManagementObject Object in WMIDataTemp1)
        {
            this.Processors.Add(new Processor(Object));
        }

        WMIDataTemp1 = DataRetriever.GetWMIData("Win32_Baseboard");
        WMIDataTemp2 = DataRetriever.GetWMIData("Win32_MotherboardDevice");
        for (int i = 0; i < WMIDataTemp1.Length; i++)
        {
            this.Motherboards.Add(new Motherboard(WMIDataTemp1[i], WMIDataTemp2[i]));
        }
        // And so on for all the other bits of hardware...
```

Comment: This might be better suited to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I didn't know of this, thanks. I'll see if anyone comes up with an answer here first.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried LINQ?

```
Processors = DataRetriever.GetWMIData("Win32_Processor").Select(x => new Processor(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: Hmm, doesn't quite work because some hardware classes need more than one WMI class to initialise.

Comment: Plus, my target framework is 2.0 which I don't think incorporates LINQ.